# RJ45 color code for cable with non-standard colors of T568D

Tags: ethernet

I have a UTP cable with the colors: white-yellow, white-black, white-red and white-purple. I would like to use this cable as an Ethernet cable. I know the color code to make straight through Ethernet cable, using the colors white-orange, white-blue, white-green and white-brown (T568B). Someone knows the RJ45 color code with the colors cable that I have?

Comment: The electrons din't really mind too much what color the insulation is. As long as you keep the same pins on the RJ45 paired like they are normally you'll be fine (1-2, 3-6, 4-5, 7-8). Are you sure the cable has good enough specs to be used as Ethernet though?

Comment: @brhans, Thanks for answering my question. I don't have a lot of electrical knowledge to answer you question, this cable is on my house. I didn't put it. Taking into account your answer, in my case how I know, for example, the color white and black, what numbers are?

Comment: Is this telephone cable?

Comment: Hi, Steve. I think that the cable is not a telephone cable, I know the telephone cable only has 4 wires and my cable has 6 wires. Sorry, I don't have too much knowledge of electronic things.

Comment: Actually, you listed 8 wires, not 6. & I'm fairly certain you have a 4-pair telephone cable from your color scheme.

Comment: @Robherc, yeap, you are right I have 8 wires and not 6 as I said. So, could I use this cable to use as an ethernet cable?

Comment: @LukeSolo - Yes, but only for a very short cable. Perhaps less than a foot or 2.  A good Ethernet interface will start by checking for maximum operating rate and adjusting accordingly, so almost certainly your cable will cause your PC to run at 10 Mbit/sec. Try it and let is know how it works.  I'm curious.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Thanks for your comment.  I could try to test the maximum operating rate, but I don't know how to get this data. Sorry but my knowledge in these topics is very limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wire your RJ45s with this cable using:

White/Yellow, Yellow, White/Black, Red, Wite/Red, Black, White/Purple, Purple

However, this **is not** ethernet-spec cat5/cat5e/cat6, so you should expect faulty performance at best. In ethernet-spec cabling, the pairs (bonded in cat6 & some cat5e) have specific twist-ratios that are 'tuned' for the signal they're supposed to carry.

In addition, the gauge/alloy of the wires & quality of the insulation is spec'd for correct performance as well.